Specifying GLVM with glmmTMB across plots and dates
I'm exploring using glmmTMB to fit a latent variable model to multivariate abundance data according to this vignette. I'm specifically interested in glmmTMB because the ordbeta() family works well with my data when including a random effect that groups sampling date by sampling plot. I'd like to expand that to examine the relationship between species as well as include additional fixed effects, but I can't figure out how to specify the the reduced-rank structure with species grouped by date and plot, or if that's even possible? I think I have too many taxa to fit interactions between taxa and fixed/random effects using a normal mixed-model strategy. I've explored other packages like gllvm, but so far glmmTMB seems like its giving the best residuals.
Here's an example using public data, should be fully reproducible:
# R 4.2.2.
library(neonUtilities) # 2.4.1
library(dplyr) # 1.1.4
library(tidyr) # 1.3.1
library(glmmTMB) # 1.1.8
library(DHARMa) # 0.4.6

# Download and format data
d0 <- neonUtilities::loadByProduct('DP1.10058.001', 'WREF', check.size = F) |>
  (`[[`)('div_1m2Data') |>
  dplyr::select(c(plotID, endDate, scientificName, percentCover)) |>
  dplyr::mutate(endDate = as.character(endDate), cover = percentCover / 100, percentCover = NULL) |>
  dplyr::filter(endDate > as.POSIXct(as.Date('2021-01-01'))) |>
  na.omit() |>
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = scientificName, values_from = cover, values_fn = mean) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -c(1, 2), names_to = 'scientificName', values_to = 'cover') |>
  dplyr::mutate(cover = ifelse(is.na(cover), 0, cover))

# glmmTMB model with only random effects for date/plot fits well, but no information on species
c0 <- glmmTMB::glmmTMBControl(optCtrl = list(iter.max = 1e3, eval.max = 1e3), start_method = list(method = NULL, jitter.sd = 0))
m0 <- glmmTMB::glmmTMB(cover ~ (1|endDate/plotID), data = d0, family = ordbeta(), control = c0, start = list())
s0 <- DHARMa::simulateResiduals(m0)

DHARMa::plotResiduals(s0, form = d0$endDate)
DHARMa::plotResiduals(s0, form = d0$plotID)
DHARMa::plotResiduals(s0, form = d0$scientificName)

# glmmTMB multi-species model with RR grouped by plotID fit poorly
m1 <- glmmTMB(cover ~ 1 + rr(scientificName + 0|plotID, d = 2), data = d0, family = ordbeta(), control = c0, start = list())
s1 <- DHARMa::simulateResiduals(m1)
DHARMa::plotResiduals(s1, form = d0$endDate)
DHARMa::plotResiduals(s1, form = d0$plotID)
DHARMa::plotResiduals(s1, form = d0$scientificName)

Any helps or perspective is appreciated!

It is not quite clear to me what you mean by

glmmTMB seems like its giving the best residuals

You write that you have "multivariate abundance data", but it is not clear from your post what kind of abundance data this is. If it is counts, using a beta response distribution is incorrect, and you should consider (e.g.,) a poisson or negative binomial model instead. If it is percentage cover of some kind, the beta response model is an excellent choice.
The models implemented by the gllvm and glmmTMB packages are equivalent. Besides a few minor implementation details they are the same, and there is little that the glmmTMB package can do that the gllvm package cannot do at this point and a few things that the gllvm package can do that the glmmTMB cannot do, but I refrain from listing them here.
Having said that, I do not generally work with glmmTMB (being one of the developers of gllvm I know that package better) but it seems that if one specifies a nested structure in the rr covariance structure this specifies separate latent variables for each grouping variable. If your goal is to have latent variables at the group-level, that is not helpful (note that a workaround is possible, so that these parameters could be fixed to be the same using the map argument in the glmmTMB package).
In the gllvm package you can fit an unconstrained ordination (as in the above) with group-level scores via de num.RR, lv.formula, and randomB arguments, as it is a type of constrained ordination afterall (covariates are involved, they're just all categorical).
library(gllvm)
data(spider, package = "mvabund")
spider$x$plot <- factor(rep(1:4, 7)) # fake "plot" variable for demo
spider$x$site <- factor(1:nrow(spider$abund))
# adjust family argument to e.g., orderedBeta or betaH if necessary
model1 <- gllvm(spider$abund, num.RR = 2, X = spider$x, lv.formula = ~(1|site/plot), family = "negative.binomial", randomB = "LV")
# alternative model with fewer random effects
model2 <- gllvm(spider$abund, num.RR = 2, X = spider$x, lv.formula = ~(1|site)+(1|plot), family = "negative.binomial", randomB = "LV")

